# How to add my project to Team foundation Server?

Tags: tfs

I have added my project to Team Foundation Server, after that i removed the Team Project and Team Project Collection. I want to add my previous project to team foundation server, this time it shows Team foundation Services are not available HTTP code 404, How do i add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a new collection using the TFS admin console. Then you can create a new project in that collection.

Comment: I have created project collection and created project. I want how to  add my vb.net project of my team (5 systems) to TFS ?